# Count rows that satisfy criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple observations (rows) per subject (`ID`) of several variables. I need to create a new variable that contains the **number of observations** that satisfy the criteria:

- `AVG_STOCK_DEN` is greater than 100
- `DIM` (observation days) are between -14 and -1

for each 'ID' (subject).

| ID | DIM | AVG_STOCK_DEN | NEW_VAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | -15 | 96 | 6 |
| 33 | -14 | 96 | 6 |
| 33 | -13 | 96 | 6 |
| 33 | -12 | 115 | 6 |
| 33 | -11 | 116 | 6 |
| 33 | -10 | 115 | 6 |
| 33 | -9 | 115 | 6 |
| 33 | -8 | 115 | 6 |
| 33 | -7 | 115 | 6 |
| 33 | -6 | 96 | 6 |
| 33 | -5 | 96 | 6 |
| 33 | -4 | 95 | 6 |
| 33 | -3 | 95 | 6 |
| 33 | -2 | 95 | 6 |
| 33 | -1 | 90 | 6 |
| 33 | 0 | 90 | 6 |
| 33 | 1 | 94 | 6 |
| 33 | 2 | 94 | 6 |
| 33 | 3 | 93 | 6 |
| 33 | 4 | 93 | 6 |

I've tried a couple of options:

1)

```py
for group in dfy_pcp.groupby('ID'):
    if (dfy_pcp['DIM'] >= -14) & (dfy_pcp['DIM'] <= -1) & (dfy_pcp['avg_stock_den'] > 100):
        dfy_pcp['days_over_100_14'] = dfy_pcp['avg_stock_den'].count().any()
    else:
         dfy_pcp['days_over_100_14'] = 0
```

2. 

```py
dfy_pcp['dfy_pcp_over_100_14'] = dfy_pcp[(dfy_pcp['DIM'] >= -14) & (dfy_pcp['DIM'] <= -1) & dfy_pcp['avg_stock_den'] > 100 ].groupby('ID')['avg_stock_den'].count().any()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the criteria you want and add `.shape[0]` in the end. Like this:

```py
total = dfy_pcp[(dfy_pcp['DIM'] >= -14) & (dfy_pcp['DIM'] <= -1) & (dfy_pcp['AVG_STOCK_DEN'] > 100)].shape[0]
```

`shape` prints the rows and the columns of a dataframe in the structure `(<rows>, <columns>)` so you take the index 0 which is the rows.

Comment: Thank you Loukas, but that does not work. after a whole day trying different things I come up with a solution, which takes the creation of two variables. the first one (dummie) assigns a value of 1 or 0 if the ['avg_stock_den'] is greater than 100, and the second one(the desired variable) creates and applies the value of the sum of days where the ['avg_stock_den'] was greater then 100 between days -14 and -1 for each subject (ID)

Answer (score 0):

### The first line creates a dummie variable assigning a value 1 for to each observation of ['avg_stock_den'] that is >100.

```
dfy_pcp['stcd_100_cnt'] = dfy_pcp[((dfy_pcp['DIM'] >= -14) & (dfy_pcp['DIM'] <= -1))]['avg_stock_den'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 100 else 0)
```

### The second line creates the desired variable with the sum of all days between -14 and -1 were ['avg_stock_den'] > 100 for each subject (ID)

```
dfy_pcp['over_100_14'] = dfy_pcp.groupby('ID')['stcd_100_cnt'].transform(lambda x: x.sum()).astype(int)
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYsm0.png)